# Sending live data between Python script and LabVIEW program

Tags: python, python-3.x, labview

I'm trying to use LabVIEW to build a program capable of executing a multitude of python scripts. So far, I'm able to execute the python scripts via LabVIEW's python module without issue. However, to improve user friendliness and communication, I want to be able to display the internal status of the python script on a LabVIEW indicator as the program runs. For instance, in one of the scripts, the program will print "Booting" to the console at the beginning, "Connecting" toward the middle, "Programming" toward the end, and "Finished" when the program is near completion.

TLDR: If anyone knows a better way to communicate live data from my Python script for display in my LabVIEW program, that would be amazingly helpful. Thank you!

I tried using LabVIEW's queues, as they're what I've used in the path to communicate between different LabVIEW loops, and between different Python threads. However, LabVIEW's python module will not take queues as a function parameter. I've also tried using LabVIEW's arrays to take advantage of Python's mutable lists, but I'm not getting any output data from that approach in LabVIEW.

Comment: I've also considered using TCP to set up a simple server to run off of my PC, but I'm unfamiliar with the intersystem communication protocols, and I'm not sure if that would be overkill, or if it would be an issue when trying to set up the program for more widespread use.

Comment: You could use TCP communication, but your Python code should be TCP client, and LabVIEW code as TCP server. You don't need to have separate server on your PC. LabVIEW TCP server will catch all the messages which Python script (TCP client) sends to the server. Also you could use UDP (but it is lossy mechanism), or Windows Pipes (LabVIEW has toolkit for that).

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have integrated Python scripts into a LabVIEW application, when a dedicated palette was not yet present, and to do so I used the technique called "Embedding Python", i.e. integrating Python into another application:
https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html

This technique is a bit more advanced, but allows you to directly iterate with Python variables and functions right from LabVIEW.